# Keras LSTM: How to give true value for every timestep (Many to many)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

This might be noob question. I have tried my best find the answers.
[image]

Basically I want LSTM to calculated error based on very timestep. I want to give true value for every timestep. I have tried giving dimension x=(2,10,1) and y=(2,10,1) which doesn't work , predict function outputs 3d array instead of 2d array. what I am doing wrong here?
I

Answer (score 0):

You should use LSTM with `return_sequences=True` followed by `Dense` layer and then flatten the output of the `Dense` layer.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


ins = Input(shape=(10, 3))  # considering 3 input features
lstm = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(ins)
dense = Dense(1)(lstm)
flat = Flatten()(dense)
model = Model(inputs=ins, outputs=flat)
model.summary()
```

This will build the following model

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10, 3)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 10, 256)           266240    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10, 1)             257       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 266,497
Trainable params: 266,497
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: I am talking about training data. Like how to x1->y1 , x2->y2 so on..... Without padding

Comment: `predict function outputs 3d array instead of 2d array. what I am doing wrong here?` then what does these lines mean?